# .SpServices working while in edit mode, stops when saving

Tags: spservices

I am trying to put a button that calls a javascript function. In this function i reference the .spservices file and all is working fine on the test site. I go to put it into production, add a content editor web part to the page, reference my file and while i am in edit mode, the spservices reference is working perfect, i have some code to test. But as soon as i hit save, the spservices stop working at all. I am not getting anywhere with this. Has anyone seen this before?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jsfiles/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jsfiles/jquery.SPServices-   2014.02.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    alert("Jquery working");
    if($().SPServices == null)
        alert("SP Services == not working");
    else
        alert("SP Services == working");

});
```

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page. Check page source and see if your java script is there. Even write a alert and check if that works

Comment: I have a function i have been using for troubleshooting.

    $(document).ready(function(){


 alert("Jquery working");
 if($().SPServices == null)
  alert("SP Services == not working");
 else
  alert("SP Services == working");

    });

The Jquery portion works fine, but the SPServices returns not working each time. Unless, i am in edit mode, then the Spservices returns working

Comment: Can you please post the code

Comment: the code has been posted